# Google Play Console and exeptions

Tags: android, google-play-console

If I catch and handle all exceptions whether Google Play Console will display these exceptions in crash report if they occur, even being handled ?

Comment: if you handle **all** exceptions (which is impossible), then your app will newer crash. And there will be no `crash report` at all.

Comment: I understand that app will not crash but still, we have the fact that exception was occurred, in that case will caught exception display in crash report to say "Hey, we've detected an exception here even if you know about it"

Comment: that is not an `exception report`, it is a `crash report`, it will report `crashes`, not `exceptions`

Comment: Ok, the simple answer, that does not require any additional thinking is `No`

Answer (score 0):

No. If you catch all exceptions then your app will not crash, and there will be nothing to report.